# Error with Pyinstaller & PyQt5 "Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories"

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I work with Anaconda 5.3.0 and Python 3.7.

An application was made and I want to create an executable file with `Pyinstaller`, the case is that I miss the following error:

> Exception: Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories Paths
>   checked:
>   C:/Miniconda3/conda-bld/qt_1535195524645/_h_env/Library/plugins

Answer (score 1):

According to [this GitHub error report](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3852), there are two main solutions:

- Run `pip install PyQt5` to install the module
- Include the flag `--exclude-module PyQt5` to prevent `pyinstaller` from trying to include it

The latter seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the anaconda command prompt try `pip install PyQt5`. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: I think the question is more "why is it asking for PyQt5 when it doesn't need it?", rather than "How can I satisfy the PyQt5 requirement?"